# Duplicate entry in database for just one user Id MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

Table: test_user_datatable

```
 id     |   user_id     |                puzzle                      

1       |    1          |           {"38":"38","39":"39"... 
259     |    1          |           {"38":"38","39":"39"...
1541    |    1          |        
1286    |    1          |        
519     |    1          |           {"38":"38","39":"39"....
```

I just checked my db, I don't know the actual cause that this duplicate data are being created in the database (table: test_user_datatable) over the time ... seems the bug but what can be the cause of it .. because  it is happening for only one user Id = 1 and all other user Id are behaving all normal..
This entry is inserting at any random time ...

How can I delete the duplicate user_id = 1 by keeping alive just the first value so that Then I make user_id column as unique value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a unique key on user_id and puzzle

```
  ALTER TABLE test_user_datatable
  ADD CONSTRAINT uCodes UNIQUE (user_id,puzzle )
```

then it will not insert duplicates.

to delete existing entries, its easy just use baeda answer.

Comment: Can I make the id values as well, all sequential, avoiding any jump due to deletion of duplicate values.. Its primary Key here

Comment: if id is promary key then you dont need do it, because it will not insert duplicates on id. just the duplicates between user_id and puzzle

Comment: No, my question is I have performed the deletion sql.. now I want to make the id value all sequential .. without any jump in Id value .. Like Id 24, 25, 26, 27 ... If 25 was duplicate it will cause the id as 24, 26,27 .... Is there any way where we can make it all sequential again.. Just a query .. If it can be ..Thanks in advance

Comment: you have id auto_increment ?

Comment: Ya its already there but due to deletion I did right now its all now with lot of random gaps.. "  
asking this beacase having non-sequential IDs is bad for index performance

Comment: You could drop the primary key column and re-create it. All the ids will then be reassigned, I assume in the order in which the rows were inserted.

Answer (score 1):

That would be `DELETE FROM test_user_datatable WHERE user_id = 1 AND id != 1`

The last condition in the `WHERE` clause (`id != <keep_alive_id>`) can be modified to whatever record you want to keep.